# Allied Telesis router: IP filtering for the LOCAL interface

Tags: router, vlan

Given an Allied Telesis router with an AlliedWare OS (2.9.1) I would like to disable access to all management services of the router except for a number of subnets (or alternatively have what is a "management VLAN" with other manufacturers' switch and router models).

What I have tried so far:

- creating a new VLAN and an appropriate IP interface, setting the LOCAL IP into this subnet, creating an IP filter for the IP interface and specifying my exclusion subnets: it simply does not work as intended as I can access the LOCAL IP set from any of the other VLAN interfaces - the traffic is apparently not going through my defined filter set at all
- creating a new IP filter set and binding it to the LOCAL IP interface: this seems not to affect any kind of traffic at all, the counters for the filter set remain at zero packets
- setting the Remote Security Officer Level IP address range: this only restricts the ability for a user with the Security Officer privilege level to log in from any but the specified address ranges / subnets. Unfortunately, it does not prevent service availability (and thus DoS capacity) or the ability to log in as a less privileged user (e.g. a "manager")
- calling technical support: unfortunately no solution so far

What I have not tried:

- creating a filter set for each and every IP interface defined on the router and excluding access to the router's management IP: I would like to reduce the overhead induced by IP filters as the router already is CPU-constrained at times. Setting up filters for every IP interface would mean that each and every traffic packet would have to pass the filters, thus consuming CPU cycles. If by any means possible, I would like to find a different solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final answer from an L2 support engineer from AT has been that it is not possible to restrict the management to a specific interface except than by setting up filter rules on all interfaces you don't want management to happen on.